# PHP FPDF With Transparent PNG's Very Slow

Tags: php, png, fpdf

I'm using FPDF with an extension I found online called TransFPDF that allows for transparent PNG's to be put into the PDF that I am dynamically generating with PHP.  The problem I am having however is that the PDF takes a long time to generate (the script takes about 30 seconds to run when I am embedding about 6 characters, where each characters is a transparent PNG.  This time also includes text and the background but I checked times and those only take about a second or two and are not slowing down the code).

I have found that the main slow point is the following function:

```
// needs GD 2.x extension 
// pixel-wise operation, not very fast 
function ImagePngWithAlpha($file,$x,$y,$w=0,$h=0,$link='') 
{ 
$tmp_alpha = tempnam('.', 'mska'); 
$this->tmpFiles[] = $tmp_alpha; 
$tmp_plain = tempnam('.', 'mskp'); 
$this->tmpFiles[] = $tmp_plain; 

list($wpx, $hpx) = getimagesize($file); 
$img = imagecreatefrompng($file); 
$alpha_img = imagecreate( $wpx, $hpx ); 

// generate gray scale pallete 
for($c=0;$c<256;$c++) ImageColorAllocate($alpha_img, $c, $c, $c); 

// extract alpha channel 
$xpx=0; 
while ($xpx<$wpx){ 
    $ypx = 0; 
    while ($ypx<$hpx){ 
        $color_index = imagecolorat($img, $xpx, $ypx); 
        $alpha = 255-($color_index>>24)*255/127; // GD alpha component: 7 bit only, 0..127! 
        imagesetpixel($alpha_img, $xpx, $ypx, $alpha); 
    ++$ypx; 
    } 
    ++$xpx; 
} 

imagepng($alpha_img, $tmp_alpha); 
imagedestroy($alpha_img); 

// extract image without alpha channel 
$plain_img = imagecreatetruecolor ( $wpx, $hpx ); 
imagecopy ($plain_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $wpx, $hpx ); 
imagepng($plain_img, $tmp_plain); 
imagedestroy($plain_img); 

//first embed mask image (w, h, x, will be ignored) 
$maskImg = $this->Image($tmp_alpha, 0,0,0,0, 'PNG', '', true); 

//embed image, masked with previously embedded mask 
$this->Image($tmp_plain,$x,$y,$w,$h,'PNG',$link, false, $maskImg); 
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas of how I could speed this up?  I can't seem to get it to go faster than about 4 seconds per character which really adds up fast (a character probably is about 1000x2000 pixels, and yes I know this is a lot, but yes it is neccessary for a printable PDF).

Thank you.

Comment: You are iterating over every single pixel in the images. ON a 300x300 image, that's 90,000 iterations PER image. What about using `imagesavealpha()` instead?

Comment: how would I use `imagesavealpha()` in this instance?  I have used it before when strictly dealing with saving images in PHP, but with this the image is transferred over to the PDF with the `$this->Image(...)` command.  I'm not sure I see how I could use it here and have it still work?  Can you please explain more?  Thanks!